# Problem using django mptt

Tags: python, django, mptt, django-mptt

I am having problem implementing django mptt.

Here is my model:

```
   class Company(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
       parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

   mptt.register(Company, order_insertion_by=['name'])
```

And

```
class Financials(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="financials")
    year = models.IntegerField()
    revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
```

So what I am looking at is how to add Financial as an child to Company.
I tried `mptt.register(Financials, parent = Company)` which of course give me error.

so mytree structure will be:

```
company1
....................> Financial1
--------------------> Financial 2

company2
-------------------->Financial 3
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to add it as a leaf node? I thought you already solved that through the foreign key relation.

Comment: Agree with Staale; you have the ForeignKey, why does Financials need to be involved in the tree structure at all?

Comment: The problem here is I am trying to do some Acl stuff here. So for that I need to save model in mptt tree structure. So If I remove the foreignkey from financial then how can I add financail as an child to company??

Answer (score 1):

Django-mptt does not support multiple types of object in the same tree.  You *could* have Financial and Company both inherit from the same parent class, and then build the tree out of instances of that parent class.  You'd need to store a "content type" field on the parent class so you can cast instances of the parent class to the proper subclass.  This is a gross hack though, as it violates the spirit of inheritance.  A Financial is not a Company, it's an attribute of a Company.  The correct answer is to fix your ACL design so you can use a ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend   django-polymorphic_tree