# How do I use django mptt?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt

I have a model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
mptt.register(Company, order_insertion_by=['name'])
```

and

```
class Financials(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
```

So how can I add `Financials` as a child to `Company` in the mptt tree structure?

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507006/problem-using-django-mptt

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291249/django-how-do-i-model-a-tree-of-heterogeneous-data-types

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow your question. A tree stores one type of object, in your case Company. To link Financials to Company just add a foreign key from Financials to Company.

If this doesn't help please expand your question to give us some more detail about what you are trying to achieve.